# Keep same height divs, scaling images but not padding

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a layout of images in columns with padding between them. I'm trying to make the columns stay the same height so the images line up at the bottom as shown in this image:
[image]

The issue is, in different screen sizes, the images (set to `width:100%;`) scale, but the padding MUST stay at 15px, so this doesn't scale. The widths of the columns will have to change to make the heights work.

I've concluded that this cannot be done in css so I've tried it with jQuery:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="eHeightStacked">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <img src="image.jpg" />
    <img src="image.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="eHeightSingle">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var eRatio1 = $('.eHeightStacked').height() / $('.eHeightStacked').width(),
    eRatio2 = $('.eHeightSingle').height() / $('.eHeightSingle').width(),
    rowWidth = $('.row').width();       

var eWidth1 = eRowWidth*eRatio2 / (eRatio1+eRatio2), 
    eWidth2 = eRowWidth-eWidth1;

$('.eHeightStacked').width( Math.round(eWidth1) );
$('.eHeightSingle').width( Math.round(eWidth2) );
```

This always puts the heights a few pixels out. Anyone know a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you set your overflow to hidden in CSS and fudge the pixels in favor of hiding a some of the edges?

Comment: Unfortunately the client won't let me crop the images at all!

Comment: Having said that, it's only a matter of 2 or 3 pixels, basically an un-noticable amount so the overflow:hidden method works a treat. As such I'll accept this answer. Thanks